# anaconda3/miniconda3 not found

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

I was following the Tutorial on

https://sd-webui.github.io/stable-diffusion-webui/docs/1.windows-installation.html

Basically

1. Install Git + miniconda
2. Clone + make env
3. run

When I did all the steps and tried to run the command webui.cmd

```
It gives me an error saying:
A:\Stable_Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui>webui.cmd
Environment name is set as ldm as per environment.yaml
anaconda3/miniconda3 not found. Install from here https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html
```

But, I was using a Miniconda Prompt and added miniconda in my path when installing it.

What could possibly cause this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4geXz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found out possible issue,

This is the solution:

create a txt file named
"`custom-conda-path.txt`" in the root and run the webui.cmd